# Ambiguous partial specialization depending on std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, typename U = void> class A;

template <class T>
class C
{
public:
    typedef T Var_t;
};

template <class T>
class B : public C<T>
{
};

template <class T>
class A<B<T>>
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "Here." << std::endl; }
};

template <class T>
class A<T, typename std::enable_if<
                             std::is_base_of<C<typename T::Var_t>, T>::value>
                             ::type>
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "There." << std::endl;}
};

int main() 
{
    A<B<int>> a;
    return 0;
}
```

When the compiler tries to instantiate the second partial specialization with the parameter `B<int>`, `std::is_base_of<C<int>, B<int>>::value` is `true`, and therefore the `std::enable_if<...>::type` returns `void` (the default type if one isn't specified). This causes an "ambiguous partial specialization" error as the compiler can't decide between the first and second partial specializations. So far, so good. However, when I replace the code within the `std::enable_if` to simply be `true` (i.e., the second partial specialization is just `template <class T> class A<T, typename std::enable_if<true>::type>`), the code compiles and runs. It outputs `"Here"`, indicating the first specialization was chosen.

My question is: If they both evaluate to `void` in the end, why does the behavior of `std::enable_if<true>::type` differ to that of `std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<...>::value>::type`?

This behavior has been tested and verified on Ideone [here](http://ideone.com/0d4p59).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `std::enable_if<true>::type` case your code defines two specialisations of the class A namely:

1. `A<B<T>, void>`
2. `A<T, std::enable_if<true>::type>`.

Those two specialisations are quite distinct from each other.  The first specialisation is narrowly focused on the type `B<T>` while the second specialisation is more general fitting any type at all.  Also, in the second specialisation the `std::enable_if` expression does not depend on `T` in any way.

For any declaration `A<X> a;` the type `X` will either match `B<something>` or not.  If it matches `B<something>` then the first specialisation will be used because it is "more specialised".  If X does not match `B<something>` then the second, more general specialisation will be used.  Either way you don't get the ambiguous error.

For more details see the discussion of Partial Ordering in [partial template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)

Now let's consider the `std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<...>::value>::type` case.

You still have two specialisations but the second specialisation is now conditional on the enable_if which in turn depends on the parameter T.

1. `A<B<T>, void>`
2. `A<T, std::enable_if<...>>`.

The type `B<int>` now matches both specialisations (to some equal extent).  Obviously it matches the `A<B<T>>, void>` specialisation but it also matches the `A<T, std::enable_if...>>` specialisation because `B<int>` is a type which satisfies the conditions imposed by the `std::enable_if` expression.

That gives you two equally valid specialisations that are candidates for your declaration of the variable `a` and so you get the "ambiguous partial specialization" error.

It might help make all this a bit more concrete if you added two more declarations to `main`

```
A<C<int>> x;
A<int>    y;
```

In the `std::enable_if<true>` case this will compile and both declarations will call the "there" constructor.

In the more complex case the declaration of `x` will compile and invoke the "there" constructor but the declaration of `y` will get a compiler error.

There is no `int::Var_t` so the `std::enable_if` expression will get a substitution failure and SFINAE will hide that specialisation.  That means there won't be any specialisation that fits `int` and you'll get the error `aggregate ‘A<int> y’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined`

Comment: So you're saying that the fact that I have some specialization on `T` makes the compiler consider `A<B<T>>` and `A<T, std::enable_if<...>>` to be equally specialized? That's a little counter-intuitive to me (I'd still expect `A<B<T>>` to be more specialized, somehow), but that makes sense.

Comment: I agree it seems a little counter-intuitive at first glance but I think perhaps that's us reading more into the code than we should?  We see `B<T>` and think "a whole class built around `T`, that must be more important than some type returned by `std::enable_if`.  But the enable test also uses `B<T>`.  Should that use be considered less significant than the other use?